# SQL LIKE query with two values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to select a row by searching for some words in a specific column.

Here is what I came up with but it's obviously not working:

```
SELECT *
FROM 'list'
WHERE 'Name' LIKE '%cat%' AND '%bengal%' AND 'Color' LIKE '%navy%'`
```

Basically I want to find this row:

```
ID | Name             | Color
---+------------------+-------------
 1 | Stuff            | Stuff
 2 | cat weird bengal | navy -> THIS
 3 | cat weird bengal | blue
 4 | Other stuff      | stuff
 5 | dog bengal       | navy
```

I searched on here but found only people who suggested `OR`, but, as you can see from the sample table, I cannot use it (or it would match with ID:5).

Is there some way to say `LIKE` 'this' AND 'that'?

Comment: SQL is a query language.  What is your DBMS?

Comment: @rory.ap I use mysql

Comment: Then why didn't you tag your question with mysql?  If you tag it properly, you attract the people with the right knowledge to answer your question.

Comment: @rory.ap Oops, sorry. Updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the same column twice:

```
SELECT * 
FROM list
 WHERE Name LIKE '%cat%' 
   AND Name LIKE '%bengal%' 
   AND Color LIKE '%navy%';
```

As [Jorge Campos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/460557/jorge-campos) mentioned you could use single `LIKE` if order is known in advance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM list
 WHERE Name LIKE '%cat%bengal%'
   AND Color LIKE '%navy%';
```

Anyway your query is not-SARGable. I would suggest using `FULL TEXT INDEX` which is RDBMS specific.

Comment: Why should I make the query sargable?

Comment: Side note, if OP knows the order he wants the words just one condition will be sufficient `name like '%cat%bengal%'`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, you are perfectly right if it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.It may help

```
SELECT * 
  FROM list 
 WHERE Name LIKE '%cat%' 
   and Name LIKE '%bengal%'  
   and Color LIKE '%navy%';
```

Or

As suggested by jorge

```
SELECT * FROM list WHERE Name LIKE '%cat%bengal%'  and Color LIKE '%navy%';
```

Comment: Op does not want a row where the text contains only cat *OR* bengal, it needs both.